# Equivalent of Ruby Enumerable#each_slice in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

I am looking for an equivalent of Ruby's Enumerable#each_slice in Javascript.

I am already using the great underscore.js that has each(), map(), inject()...

Basically, in Ruby this great method does this :

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10].each_slice(3) {|a| p a}

# outputs below
[1, 2, 3]
[4, 5, 6]
[7, 8, 9]
[10]
```

Comment: For anyone looking for a jQuery solution there is https://github.com/burin/jquery-each_slice

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I would modify Brandan's answer slightly to fit better within  the environment of JavaScript plus underscore.js:

```
_.mixin({ "eachSlice": function(obj, size, iterator, context) {
    for (var i=0, l=obj.length; i < l; i+=size) {
      iterator.call(context, obj.slice(i,i+size), i, obj);
    } }});
```

Here's a [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/p0fe776L/).

Comment: Sorry, how do I use this?

Comment: first, the code assumes you're already using `underscore.js`; there's no `_` object with a `mixin` method otherwise. If you've loaded underscore and run the above code, you will then have an `_.eachSlice` method that works as requested; see the jsfiddle demo linked in my answer.

Answer (score 13):

How about this:

```
Array.prototype.each_slice = function (size, callback){
  for (var i = 0, l = this.length; i < l; i += size){
    callback.call(this, this.slice(i, i + size));
  }
};

[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10].each_slice(3, function (slice){
  console.log(slice);
});
```

Output (in Node.js):

```
[ 1, 2, 3 ]
[ 4, 5, 6 ]
[ 7, 8, 9 ]
[ 10 ]
```

Comment: Give Mark Reed's answer a shot too. I'm not familiar with underscore.js.

Answer (score 6):

I've found `_.chunk` in lodash is a better solution now

```
var chunk = require('lodash/array/chunk');

_.chunk(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], 2);
// -> [['a', 'b'], ['c', 'd']]
```

https://lodash.com/docs#chunk