# each_slice like in javascript from ruby using opal

Tags: javascript, ruby

in Ruby i can do something like this

```
irb(main):038:0> (1..100).each_slice(5) {|x| p x}
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
[6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
[11, 12, 13, 14, 15]
[16, 17, 18, 19, 20]
[21, 22, 23, 24, 25]
[26, 27, 28, 29, 30]
[31, 32, 33, 34, 35]
[36, 37, 38, 39, 40]
[41, 42, 43, 44, 45]
[46, 47, 48, 49, 50]
[51, 52, 53, 54, 55]
[56, 57, 58, 59, 60]
[61, 62, 63, 64, 65]
[66, 67, 68, 69, 70]
[71, 72, 73, 74, 75]
[76, 77, 78, 79, 80]
[81, 82, 83, 84, 85]
[86, 87, 88, 89, 90]
[91, 92, 93, 94, 95]
[96, 97, 98, 99, 100]
```

maybe I am rusting in javascript though been doing it for my everyday job. I have been hacking this in js for days already. any suggestions?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Already asked and answered here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10249658/equivalent-of-ruby-enumerableeach-slice-in-javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out Opal! http://opalrb.org/try/

Copy and paste your code there...

If you're wondering how to get started with raw html and javascript, run irb, and type the following: (after doing `gem install opal`)

```
require 'opal'
File.open('opal.js', 'w') do |f|
  f.write(Opal::Builder.build('opal'))
end
```

This will generate `opal.js` for you

In order to get the javascript for your ruby code, you can do in irb:

```
puts Opal.compile("(1..100).each_slice(5) {|x| p x}")
```

You get the conversion of your ruby code to javascript:

```
/* Generated by Opal 0.5.5 */
(function($opal) {
  var $a, $b, TMP_1, self = $opal.top, $scope = $opal, nil = $opal.nil, $breaker = $opal.breaker, $slice = $opal.slice, $range = $opal.range;
  $opal.add_stubs(['$each_slice', '$p']);
  return ($a = ($b = ($range(1, 100, false))).$each_slice, $a._p = (TMP_1 = function(x){var self = TMP_1._s || this;if (x == null) x = nil;
  return self.$p(x)}, TMP_1._s = self, TMP_1), $a).call($b, 5)
})(Opal);
```

Now create a new html file in the same directory as opal.js

```
<html>
<head>
<script src='opal.js'></script>
<script>
// copy the javascript above here
</script>
</head>
</html>
```

Open the html file and check the console, you should see:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
[6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
[11, 12, 13, 14, 15]
[16, 17, 18, 19, 20]
[21, 22, 23, 24, 25]
[26, 27, 28, 29, 30]
```

etc...

Comment: Greetings, hey 
thank you for the suggestion! I like it! but it requires me to install a library.. this will work but adding a new library is not what i am thinking... is there anything that works like each_slice from ruby without adding new library? I have lodash and underscore though.

Comment: Someone gave you a link in a comment above =) ... I updated my answer to show you how to get started with Opal in case you wish to =)

Comment: it worked!, now I have a tool for translating my ruby codes to JS. thank you!. generated the opal.js then throwed it to my assets folder and the translated code works

Comment: Great to hear! Awesome :-)

Comment: You could use their gems if you want to integrate with rails and sprockets... I was just showing you how to get started with pure html and js