# HTML/CSS Tables. Having only 6 a certain number of columns and then the table starts again below

Tags: html, css, html-table

My title might be a bit confusing so I'll make a sort of a scheme, my point is I want to have a maximum number of columns on each line and then have the table continue below it, like this:

```
| Header 1 | header 2 | header 3 |
| cell 1   | cell 2   | cell 3   |
| Header 4 | header 5 | header 6 |
| cell 4   | cell 5   | cell 6   |
```

Is there any way at all to make a table do this?

The code looks pretty much like this:

```
<table class="shop_table" border="1">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      {% for color in color_list %}
      <th class="image_t">{{color.nome}}</th>
      {%endfor%}
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      {% for color in color_list %}
      <td class="image_f">
        <img src="/media/{{ color.imagem }}" style="width:50px;height:50px;" alt=""></a>
      </td>
      {%endfor%}
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Yes, this is a 3x4 table? I don't see the problem.

Comment: Oh wait, you mean you want to do this in a responsive way, only if the screen isn't wide enough to show all 6 columns side by side?

Comment: Certainly should be achievable, but it's not a very good design and recommend against it.

Comment: Pretty much yea, and this is working with for statements, so they're also added automatically.
I'll add the code up there.

Answer (score 1):

If I'm understanding correctly, yes.

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>table</th>
    <th>header</th>
    <th>here</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>table</td>
    <td>row</td>
    <td>here</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>table</th>
    <th>header</th>
    <th>here</th>
  </tr>
 <tr>
    <td>table</td>
    <td>row</td>
    <td>here</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

EDIT:

FOR ERB use `<% @colors.each_slice(3) do |color| %>`
This will take three at a time so you can format it correctly in your code.
Documentation: http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_slice

Comment: Same problem, they always end up stacked up on a vertical single column.

Comment: Lol sorry, I got trigger happy. It would be something similar though I would think... Maybe this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10249658/equivalent-of-ruby-enumerableeach-slice-in-javascript

Comment: Hmmm, nope. This looks like a good way to make matrices tho but it wouldnt work for what i'm doing since i would have to have the database organized in a different way.

Answer (score 0):

I don't fully understand your question - are you looking to create multiple rows, but maintain the column (header) always above the lower cell?

Something like you describe should definitely be achievable, and I personally wouldn't recommend using tables at all. Instead, just create a  that contains header1cell1 stacked on top of each other with a set width of 33% of it's parent container. Do this 6 times, and I believe you should have the layout you're looking for.

Comment: That's what i tried to do but they all end up on top of each other for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

- Make the table a flex container
- Use `display: contents` on the table body, head, and rows to prevent them from generating boxes. This way the cells will be flex items.
- Use `order` to arrange the cells as desired.
- Use `break-after` (old browsers `page-break-after`) to force line breaks.

I think currently this will only work on Firefox.

```css
table {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-content: flex-start;
}
thead, tbody, tr {
  display: contents;
}
td {
  display: block;
  border: 1px solid;
}
tbody td:nth-child(n+4) {
  page-break-after: always;
  break-after: always;
}
thead td:nth-child(1), tbody td:nth-child(1) { order: 1; }
thead td:nth-child(4), tbody td:nth-child(4) { order: 2; }
thead td:nth-child(2), tbody td:nth-child(2) { order: 3; }
thead td:nth-child(5), tbody td:nth-child(5) { order: 4; }
thead td:nth-child(3), tbody td:nth-child(3) { order: 5; }
thead td:nth-child(6), tbody td:nth-child(6) { order: 6; }
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <td>Header 1</td><td>Header 2</td><td>Header 3</td><td>Header 4</td><td>Header 5</td><td>Header 6</td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Cell 1</td><td>Cell 2</td><td>Cell 3</td><td>Cell 4</td><td>Cell 5</td><td>Cell 6</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Yep this would only work on firefox since the snippet here appears as a single vertical column.